# Getting Error System.LimitException: Too many Email Invocations: 11 in Apex Salesforce

Tags: apex, email

I tried to make report summary that will be sent to email, this is my code now.
But i got System.LimitException: Too many Email Invocations: 11, what sould i do to avoid this error? should i made an batch? but how to make it? need

```
Global class UT_MDM_Email_MonthlyReport implements Schedulable {
    Global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
          prepare_data(); 
    }
    
    Global static void prepare_data()   {   
        List<String> lstOwnerPlant = new List<String>();
        List<String> lstBranchsite = new List<String>();

        list<aggregateresult> lstPlantSite = [SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name plant
                                               FROM Contact 
                                               WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Is_Drop__c = FALSE AND SOURCE__C IN ('SPS')
                                               GROUP BY Owner.UserRole.Name];
        list<aggregateresult> lsBranchSite = [SELECT Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name site
                                               FROM Contact 
                                               WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Is_Drop__c = FALSE AND SOURCE__C IN ('FSL') AND Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name != NULL
                                               GROUP BY Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name];
        
        for(AggregateResult ctc : lstPlantSite)
        {
            lstOwnerPlant.add(ctc.get('plant').toString());
        }
        
        for(AggregateResult ctcSite : lsBranchSite)
        {
            lstBranchsite.add(ctcSite.get('site').toString());
        }
        
        if(lstOwnerPlant.size() > 0){
           for(String req : lstOwnerPlant)
            {
                sendMailForYa(req, 'SPS');
            } 
        }
        
        if(lstBranchsite.size() > 0){
           for(String req : lstBranchsite)
            {
                sendMailForYa(req,'FSL');
            } 
        }
    } 
    
    
    public static void sendMailForYa(String plantSite, string sourceVal)
    {
        System.debug('sendMailForYa');
        map<string,List<aggregateresult>> mapPlant = new map<string,List<aggregateresult>>();
        map<string,List<aggregateresult>> mapSite = new map<string,List<aggregateresult>>();

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> masterListMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        
        List<Contact> LContact = new List<Contact>();
        Set<String> setPlantSite = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> setSource = new Set<String>();
        List<String> setArea = new List<String>();
        if(sourceVal == 'FSL'){
            for(AggregateResult fslEmailCont : [SELECT Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name parentTerritory, Branch_Site_Support__r.Area_Name__c area
                                            FROM Contact 
                                            WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Is_Drop__c = FALSE AND Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name = :plantSite AND Branch_Site_Support__r.Area_Name__c != NULL
                                            GROUP BY Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name,Branch_Site_Support__r.Area_Name__c ])
            {
                setPlantSite.add((string)fslEmailCont.get('parentTerritory'));
                setSource.add('FSL');
                setArea.add((string)fslEmailCont.get('area'));
            }
        }
        
        if(sourceVal == 'SPS'){
            for(AggregateResult spsEmailCont : [SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name OwnerRole,Owner.Area_Name__c area
                                            FROM Contact 
                                            WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Is_Drop__c = FALSE AND Owner.UserRole.Name = :plantSite AND Owner.Area_Name__c != NULL 
                                            GROUP BY Owner.UserRole.Name,Owner.Area_Name__c])
            {
                setPlantSite.add((string)spsEmailCont.get('OwnerRole'));
                setSource.add('SPS');
                setArea.add((string)spsEmailCont.get('area'));
            } 
        }

        System.debug('CEK SET YASH : Plant' +  setPlantSite + ' setSource : '+ setSource + ' setArea : '+ setArea);
        if(setPlantSite != null && setSource != null && setArea != null ){  
            String strPlantSite = String.join(new List<String>(setPlantSite), ',');
            String strSource = String.join(new List<String>(setSource), ',');
            String strArea = String.join(new List<String>(setArea), ',');
            
            System.debug('strPlantSite + strPlantSite :' + strPlantSite + ' '+ strPlantSite);
            String header_letter = '<p>Dengan Hormat, </p>';
            String body_letter = '<p>Berikut ini kami sampaikan summary status contact yang ada di cabang/site: </p><br/>';
            String table_letter = getTableEmailBody(strPlantSite);  //tambah parameter branchsite/owner plant
            String footer_letter = '<br/><br/>Terimakasih<br/> - Salesforce System';
            String letter = header_letter + body_letter + table_letter + footer_letter;
            
            // Define the email
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            
            // Set list of peoples who should recieve an email
            List<String> Str_ToAddress = new List<String>();
            List<String> CC_ToAddress = new List<String>();
            List<String> ltolist; 
           
            //Set CC Email Reminder
            String ccLabel = System.Label.UT_Contact_MDM_CC;    //CC Label Rizki, Pak Wijang dan Pak Eko
            List<String> lcclist = ccLabel.split(',');
            
            //label for CSSD
            String UT_MDM_CC_Site_1A_1B_SPS = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Site_1A_1B_SPS;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Site_2A_2B_SPS = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Site_2A_2B_SPS;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Site_3A_3B_SPS = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Site_3A_3B_SPS;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area1_SPS = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area1_SPS;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area2_SPS = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area2_SPS;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area3_SPS = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area3_SPS;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Site_1A_1B_FSL = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Site_1A_1B_FSL;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Site_2A_2B_FSL = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Site_2A_2B_FSL;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Site_3A_3B_FSL = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Site_3A_3B_FSL;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area1_FSL = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area1_FSL;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area2_FSL = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area2_FSL;
            String UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area3_FSL = System.Label.UT_MDM_CC_Branch_Area3_FSL;   
            
            //coba cari cara gmn query biar bisa dapatin BM, PDH dan SDH Based on setPlantSite
            String nameOfPlantSite;
            if(strPlantSite.contains('MDN')){
               nameOfPlantSite = 'Medan';             
            }else if(strPlantSite.contains('PKB')){
               nameOfPlantSite = 'Pekanbaru';   
            }
            System.debug('nameOfPlantSite :' +nameOfPlantSite + ' strPlantSite:'+ strPlantSite);
            string nameOfBMPlantSite = nameOfPlantSite + ' BM';
            
            List<User> get_CC_BM = [SELECT Id, Name,Email, ProfileId, UserType, Plant__c, Area_Name__c, UserRole.Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name =:nameOfBMPlantSite AND isActive = TRUE];
            System.debug('get_CC_BM : '+ get_CC_BM + ' nameOfBMPlantSite :' + nameOfBMPlantSite);
            for(User getBM : get_CC_BM){
                lcclist.add(getBM.Email);
            }
            //get PDH
            string nameOfPDH = 'Parts Department Head - ' + strPlantSite + ' SPS';
            List<User> get_to_PDH = [SELECT Id, Name,Email, ProfileId, UserType, Plant__c, Area_Name__c, UserRole.Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name =:nameOfPDH AND isActive = TRUE];
            for(User getPDH : get_to_PDH){
                Str_ToAddress.add(getPDH.Email);
            }
            System.debug('get_to_PDH : '+ Str_ToAddress + ' nameOfPDH :' + nameOfPDH);
            String nameOfSDH = nameOfPlantSite + ' SDH';
            List<User> get_to_SDH = [SELECT Id, Name,Email, ProfileId, UserType, Plant__c, Area_Name__c, UserRole.Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name =:nameOfSDH AND isActive = TRUE];
            for(User getPDH : get_to_SDH){
                Str_ToAddress.add(getPDH.Email);
            }           System.debug('get_to_SDH : '+ Str_ToAddress + ' nameOfSDH :'+ nameOfSDH);               
                            
        CC_ToAddress = lcclist;
        email.setToAddresses(Str_ToAddress);
        email.setSenderDisplayName(' - Salesforce System');
        email.setCcAddresses((CC_ToAddress != NULL ? CC_ToAddress : NULL));
        
        // Sets the paramaters of the email
        email.setSubject( System.Label.UT_MDM_Subject + ' '+ (strPlantSite != null? strPlantSite : '')); 
        email.setHtmlBody( letter );
        masterListMails.add(email);
        }

        System.debug('Master List Mails : ' + masterListMails.size());
         //Send List Mail 
        if(masterListMails.size() > 0)
        {
            List<Contact> lscon = new List<Contact>();
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(masterListMails);
            if(results[0].success){
              System.debug('The email was sent successfully');    
            }else {
              System.debug('The email failed to send: ' +  results[0].errors[0].message);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static string getTableEmailBody(String Fromadd)
    {
        System.debug('Fromadd :' + Fromadd);
        String htmlbody = '';
        
        //open table..
        htmlBody = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><caption>SUMMARY STATUS CONTACT</caption><tr><th>PLANT</th><th>TOTAL</th><th>VALIDATE</th><th>NEED FOLLOW UP</th><th>STATUS</th>';
        
        List<ContactWrapper> wraps = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        
        //FSL - Based on Branchsite
        list<aggregateresult> fslCont = [SELECT Count(Id) totalNFU, Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name branchsite, NEED_FOLLOW_UP__c FROM Contact 
                                        WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name =: Fromadd AND is_drop__c = FALSE AND Source__c = 'FSL'
                                        GROUP BY Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name, NEED_FOLLOW_UP__c ORDER BY Branch_Site_Support__r.ParentTerritory.Name, NEED_FOLLOW_UP__c];
        System.debug('fslCont :' + fslCont + ' size: ' +fslCont.size());
        
        //SPS - Based on Owner Plant
        list<aggregateresult> spsCont = [SELECT Count(Id) totalNFU, Owner.UserRole.Name plant, NEED_FOLLOW_UP__c FROM Contact 
                                         WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Owner.UserRole.Name =: Fromadd AND is_drop__c = FALSE AND Source__c = 'SPS'
                                         GROUP BY Owner.UserRole.Name, NEED_FOLLOW_UP__c ORDER BY Owner.UserRole.Name, NEED_FOLLOW_UP__c];
        
        map<string,List<aggregateresult>> mapFSLCont = new map<string,List<aggregateresult>>();
        map<string,List<aggregateresult>> mapSPSCont = new map<string,List<aggregateresult>>();
        System.debug('spsCont :' + spsCont + ' size: ' +spsCont.size());
        
        for(AggregateResult agrFSL: fslCont){
            if(mapFSLCont.containsKey((string)agrFSL.get('branchsite'))){
                mapFSLCont.get((string)agrFSL.get('branchsite')).add(agrFSL);
            }
            else{
                mapFSLCont.put((string)agrFSL.get('branchsite'),new List<aggregateresult>{agrFSL});
            }
        }
       
        for(AggregateResult agrSPS: spsCont){
            if(mapSPSCont.containsKey((string)agrSPS.get('plant'))){
                mapSPSCont.get((string)agrSPS.get('plant')).add(agrSPS);
            }
            else{
                mapSPSCont.put((string)agrSPS.get('plant'),new List<aggregateresult>{agrSPS});
            }
        }
        System.debug('Check mapSPSCont List : '+ mapSPSCont);
        System.debug('Check mapFSLCont List : '+ mapFSLCont);
        
        for (String key : mapFSLCont.keySet()) {
            Integer ac; Integer nonac;
            List<AggregateResult> lstAgr = mapFSLCont.get(key);
            for(AggregateResult mapLstFSL: lstAgr ){
                if(mapLstFSL.get('Need_Follow_Up__c') == false){
                    System.debug('FALSE' +mapLstFSL.get('totalNFU') );
                    ac = (Integer) mapLstFSL.get('totalNFU');
                }
                else{
                    nonac = (Integer) mapLstFSL.get('totalNFU');
                }
            }
            wraps.add(new ContactWrapper(key,ac,nonac));     
            System.debug('### lines.get(key) : ' + lstAgr + 'Wrap' + wraps);
            
        }
        
         for (String key : mapSPSCont.keySet()) {
            Integer ac; Integer nonac;
            List<AggregateResult> lstAgr = mapSPSCont.get(key);
            for(AggregateResult mapLstSPS: lstAgr ){
                if(mapLstSPS.get('Need_Follow_Up__c') == false){
                    ac = (Integer) mapLstSPS.get('totalNFU');
                }
                else{
                    nonac = (Integer) mapLstSPS.get('totalNFU');
                }
            }
            wraps.add(new ContactWrapper(key,ac,nonac));     
            System.debug('### lines.get(key) 2 : ' + lstAgr + 'Wrap' + wraps);
            
        }
        
        for(ContactWrapper wrapCont : wraps){
            String myBranch = wrapCont.tempBranchSite; if(wrapCont.tempBranchSite == null){myBranch = '-';}
            Integer myNFU = wrapCont.tempTotalNFU; if(wrapCont.tempTotalNFU == null){myNFU = 0;}
            Integer myValidate = wrapCont.tempTotalVal; if(wrapCont.tempTotalVal == null){myValidate = 0;}
            Integer myTotal = myValidate + myNFU;
            Decimal myValPers = (Decimal) myValidate/myTotal*100; Double myValPersentage = myValPers.setScale(2);
            Decimal myNFUPers = (Decimal) myNFU/myTotal*100; Double myNFUPersentage = myNFUPers.setScale(2);
            
            String myStatus;
            if(myValPersentage < 25){
              myStatus = 'Urgent';  
            }else if(myValPersentage >= 25 && myValPersentage <= 75){
              myStatus = 'Attention';    
            }else{
              myStatus = 'Normal';   
            }
            htmlBody += '<tr><td rowspan="2">'+myBranch+'</td><td rowspan="2">' + myTotal + '</td><td>' + myValidate +'</td><td>' +myNFU
+'</td><td rowspan="2" >'+ myStatus + '</td></tr>' +
                        '<tr><td>' + myValPersentage +'%' + '</td><td>' +myNFUPersentage +'%'+ '</td></tr>';        }
        
        //close table...
        htmlBody += '</table>';
        System.debug('Table ->' + htmlBody);
        return htmlBody;
    }
    
    
    public class ContactWrapper{
        public String tempBranchSite { get; set; }
        public Integer tempTotalNFU   { get; set; }
        public Integer tempTotalVal { get; set; }
        
        public ContactWrapper(String branchsite, Integer totalNFU, Integer totalVal) {
            this.tempBranchSite = branchsite;
            this.tempTotalNFU = totalNFU;
            this.tempTotalVal = totalVal;
            System.debug('This is Contact Wrapp: ' + tempBranchSite + ' ' + tempTotalNFU + ' ' + tempTotalVal);
        }
    } }
```

Comment: One of the options could be to refactor the code in order to construct a collection of all emails to be sent, and send it in the end of the code with Messaging.sendEmail to call it only once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385111&type=1) "*There is no email limit from Apex. The limit is on the number of times the sendEmail() method can be invoked from Apex.*"

As you are calling the sendMail method inside a loop you are hitting the limit.

```
    if(lstOwnerPlant.size() > 0){
       for(String req : lstOwnerPlant)
        {
            sendMailForYa(req, 'SPS');
        } 
    }
    
    if(lstBranchsite.size() > 0){
       for(String req : lstBranchsite)
        {
            sendMailForYa(req,'FSL');
        } 
    }
```

Suggestions:

*From the method return the SingleEmailMessage.*

```
public static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage getMailForYa(String plantSite, string sourceVal) {
    ......
    ......
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    ......
    ......
    return email;
}
```

*In the for loop, add the the SingleEmailMessage to a list and then send after the loop completes.*

```
.....
.....
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> masterListMailsYa = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
.....
.....
if(lstOwnerPlant.size() > 0){
   for(String req : lstOwnerPlant) {
        masterListMailsYa.add(getMailForYa(req, 'SPS'));
    } 
}
.....
.....
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(masterListMailsYa);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much u save my day :))